# How execute UTF-8 scripts in unitils / DBunit

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, dbunit, unitils

I wrote all SQL scripts for tests using UTF-8. All my java code uses UTF-8 charset. When I tried execute the tests, the unitils/DBunit read them as other encoding (maybe ISO 8859-1).

My database is ORACLE. I tried set 'NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8' in my enviroment. This setting works in sqlplus, but, no effect in DBunit execution.

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue adding this VM parameter in java command:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Sergio Marcelo

Comment: Also works when adding this to <property name="javaVmArguments"> in arquillian.xml